# Whether to use var or let during instances creation in Swift?

Tags: swift, instance, constants, var, let

What should be used to create the instances of classes in Swift and why?

please explain the usage of let and var during the instances creation in Swift

below is the code :-

```
class ConstantTest{
    let constant: String
    init(constant: String) {
        self.constant = constant
    }
    func printConstant() {
        print(constant)
    }
}

let constanttest = ConstantTest(constant: "Hello")
constanttest.printConstant()

var test = ConstantTest(constant: "Hie")
test.printConstant()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `let` if:

- it is a constant (or in the case of reference types like `class`, if the reference cannot be replaced with another reference); and
- you're able to set it during the initialization process.

But if you need to be able to change it at a later point, use `var`, such as true variables whose values are not constant (or in the case of reference types, if you need to replace it with another instance). But variables and properties whose values are not set during the initialization process, you have to use `var`. For example, `lazy` stored properties use `var` because their value is not set when the initialization process completes, but only when you first reference it. Another example includes view controllers' references to their outlets that are hooked up only when the view hierarchy is created at a later point.

Needless to say, computed properties use `var`, too.

But, if you can use `let`, you should do so, as it's easier to write safe code if you know what is a constant and what is a variable. In your example, you'd use `let`.

Note: In the case of reference types, like `class` types, `let` does not mean that that the object itself is necessarily immutable, merely that you cannot replace it with another instance. If you want to enjoy control over whether it's immutable or not, consider using a value type (e.g. a `struct`).

---

Let me see if I can make that final note more clear. Consider:

```
class Foo {
    var value: String
    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Then the following is permitted:

```
let obj = Foo(value: "a")
obj.value = "b"           // changing mutable property of reference type, Foo, is permitted
```

But the following is not:

```
let obj = Foo(value: "a")
obj = Foo(value: "b")     // replacing `obj` with a new instance of `Foo`, is not
```

If you don't want to be able to change `value` property, you can define `value` to be immutable (or at least, not publicly mutable), e.g.:

```
class Foo {
    let value: String      // or `private(set) var value: String`
    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Or don't define `Foo` as `class` (a reference type) and instead define it to be a `struct` (a value type):

```
struct Foo {
    var value: String
    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

let obj = Foo(value: "a")
obj.value = "b"            // this is not permitted, because Foo value-type, `obj`, was declared with `let`, making it immutable
```

Note, that final example, declaring `Foo` as a value type (a `struct`) does change it fairly fundamentally, e.g.

```
var obj1 = Foo(value: "a")
var obj2 = obj1            // this value is a copy of `obj1` not a reference to the same object that `obj1` pointed to
obj1.value = "b"
print("\(obj1.value)")     // will print "b"
print("\(obj2.value)")     // will print "a"
```

But value types, while it requires a slightly different mindset to use them, are incredibly useful for easily writing safe code. See WWDC 2015 [Building Better Apps with Value Types in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/414/).

Comment: Thanks @Rob , but my doubt is,  Class instances should be created with var or let constant and why ?

Comment: The rule is the same. Use `let` unless you have to use `var`. if you use `let`, you're making explicit that this reference cannot be replaced with another. (It obviously says nothing about whether the object is mutable or not ... consider using value type, i.e. `struct` for that.)

Comment: I tried assigning the let instance to a new var instance and got no error even i was able to modify the value after changing the class property to var.             `var testnew = constanttest    testnew.constant = "hey"    print(testnew.constant`

Comment: @abhinavjha - Yes, that was my last point. Note, you can change `constant` not because `testnew` was declared as a `var` (that's a red herring), but merely because regardless if you use `let` when defining `obj` in my example, if the `class` was defined to be mutable, using `let` when you instantiate it does change the fact that the object, itself, it is still mutable. Only the pointer to it is immutable. I've added some code snippets to the end of my question to illustrate this point. All of this behavior changes if you use value-types (i.e. `struct`).

Answer (score 1):

There are varying reasons to use each. The simplest way to explain this is that `let` is for defining constants, while `var` is for defining variables. When using `let` the value cannot be changed. So in your application if you need a value that can be changed, use `var`. As well you might think of searching for your answer, as there are many duplicates of this question.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: Actually I am not understanding what difference we will get while creating instances with var or let. I am aware of var and let functionality for class properties etc.

Comment: Using `let` in this situation would be correct according to my minimal understanding of Swift, as the instance of the type never changes. For instance, if you needed to replace that instance with a new one, however, it would not be applicable to use `let`.

So if you needed to do this, it would be `var`.

`constanttest = ConstantTest(constant: "new test")`

Comment: I tried assigning the let instance to a new var instance and got no error even i was able to modify the value after changing the class property to var. @Rob (NOTE :- My Doubt is regarding instances should be created with var or let constant) `var testnew = constanttest`
`testnew.constant = "hey"`
`print(testnew.constant)`